# Entities framework advanced calculated fields?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm looking for the best way to handle columns which are calculated on the database (not at the client). The reason for that is performance.

For example this is an invoicing program, and next to each customer I want to display a current balance (all invoice amounts minus all payment amounts). I can think of 3 ways to accomplish this:

1) adding a property to the Customer class which calculates the balance on the client side. This is obviously not efficient; this is what I currently do.

2) Can I use entity sql to calculate it at the db? i don't know entity sql at all so before i go learning I want to know if it's even possible / practical for this.

3) create a view on the database and map to that instead of the table

Am I missing something better? Which is best?

Thanks!
-Carl

[edit] For what it's worth, option #3 seems the most practical to me. I created the view but now I encounter a problem when associating it to the original table - the problem is described here: [Entities framework mapping association between view and table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336185/entities-framework-mapping-association-between-view-and-table)

Comment: How up-to-date does the balance have to be? A calculation that involves selecting and processing a bunch of rows from another table is always going to introduce some overhead, so maybe it's better to calculate it in a batch process rather than on-demand?

Even if batch processing is not an option, thinking about the acceptable staleness may mean you can consider some sort of caching approach.

Comment: it might be acceptable, but for the purpose of learning (i am new to entities framework), simplicity, and 100%-accuracy, I would prefer to make it a real-time calculation. this invoicing app is for my own use so the database is quite small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties to your Customer class in a "partial class". You can perform the calculations in the additional property; just add a file to the project and define the class as partial class Customer. It will not be overwritten when you regenerate your model code.