# Best practice to merge Table Entity with View Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is there any better way to merge a **Entity Table** with a **Entity View**

A little example: I have a **Person** table with:

**id**,

**name**,

**lastname**

columns and a view named **ViewPersonLastLocations** with:

**person_id**

**location_name**.

I need to display **Person** table with the information of **ViewPersonLastLocations**.
Actually i can **"merge"** those entities with two foreachs, and i create a variable in the **Person partial class**.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You need `join` and have another class that represents a view for the resulting data.

Comment: Yes, besides doing a Linq `JOIN` you could reference the view as a navigation property and use `Include` to access it.

Comment: I can't, because there isn't any virtual variable from Person and ViewPersonLastLocations @SteveGreene

Comment: With Join it creates something like **{ Person = {Entity.Person}, ViewPersonLastLocations = {Entity.ViewPersonLastLocations}}** and i need something like **{ Person = {Entity.Person}}** with the ViewPersonLastLocation inside @trailmax

Comment: @JohanSánchez what do you mean "inside"? create another class that has required structure and populate it from your join request.

Comment: @trailmax the idea is to avoid to creater another class and find a way to put ViewPersonLastLocations in Person using Include(). I tried to create a relation between those tables in my .edmx file, but it doesn't work

Comment: @JohanSánchez Why avoid another class? Classes are cheap to create - they don't have to be part of your DB.

Comment: But i can't create/update/delete using a custom class, or there is a way to create/update/delete using a custom class?(For example finding the Person using the ID of person in the custom class) @trailmax

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear on what you want based on your last comment, but will start with this code for a join if the relationship is 1:1. If it is 1:Many, then it is similar, but project into a collection.

```
var personWithLocation = context.Persons
        .SelectMany(p => context.ViewPersonLastLocations
                                .Where(vp => vp.person_id == p.id)
                                .DefaultIfEmpty(),
                         (p, vp) => new PersonViewModel  // create a viewmodel for results or anonymous
                         {
                             Id = p.id,
                             Name = p.name,
                             LastName = p.lastname,
                             LocationName = vp.location_name
                         }
                     ).ToList();
```

Comment: For example, using a Include("ViewPersonLastLocations ") when i create a new List of Person, but the problem is there isn't any connection between Person and ViewPersonLastLocations.

Comment: I don't know how to do that with Database First. Pretty simple with Code First though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336185/entities-framework-mapping-association-between-view-and-table